# How to fetch messages from Kafka that host in virtualbox vm

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I tried to fetch messages by Java client from host OS . I configured bridge network between host and guest , kafka is running but java client was stuck when try to do `ConsumerRecords<String,String> records = consumers.poll(100);` 
My kafka in guest OS listening on localhost:9092

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your Consumer properties?

There are a couple of properties to validate in you `server.properties` file: `listeners` and `advertised.listeners`. You can check this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whycan'tmyconsumers/producersconnecttothebrokers?